# Dapper How to Handle DBNull by DynamicParameter.Get

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

```
var param = new DynamicParameters();
param.Add("MsgId", DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);

connection.Execute(MessageSelOutMessageId, param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
count = param.Get<int>("MsgId");
```

By referencing Dapper, I used the code above to call a Stored Procedure with an output parameter - MsgId. It is working fine, but in some cases, there would be no value returned from the Stored Procedure and the returned output parameter value would be null. In these cases, I got this exception :

> Attempting to cast a DBNull to a non nullable type! Note that out/return parameters will not have updated values until the data stream completes (after the 'foreach' for Query(..., buffered: false), or after the GridReader has been disposed for QueryMultiple)

I'd understood that we could mark the return Data Type as nullable to avoid this error by using the code below

```
count = param.Get<int?>("MsgId");
```

But, is there any other way to check **param.Get("MsgId")** == null instead of using nullable data type - **int?**

Comment: Maybe `param.Get<dynamic>("MsgId") == null`?

Comment: Can you try DBNull.Value instead of null, these two are different

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Paulius, tried with dynamic datatype 
    `count = param.Get<dynamic>("MsgId");` and it work as what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was due to the **Id** parameter in stored proc was set as **IN** and at last, I was also setting its value to **LAST_INSERT_ID()** whereas in my C# (Dapper code) it was made **ParameterDirection.InputOutput**.

After I made my stored proc ID as **INOUT**, the problem got resolved.

In short what I understood was that the **Id** parameter behaviour (IN/OUT/INOUT) should be in sync at both the places i.e in stored proc and C#.

Answer (score 1):

You know handle by add nullable int and cast to int nullable to code  for bind value null :

```
count = (int?) param.Get<int?>("MsgId");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).